# Film about a spacecraft AI trying to breed a new mechanic

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

This was a film which features a spacecraft that has an AI. There is only one man and one woman in the movie. The man is the only one on the spaceship and he is just there as a mechanic.

The AI wants a new mechanic. It meets up with another spaceship that has a woman on it so they can procreate and breed a new mechanic to train. The man and woman catch on to this and rebel against the AI.

That's pretty much the movie in a nutshell.

Does anyone know what the movie is?

Comment: Are you sure this was a movie and not part of a TV show?

Comment: It's an outer limits episode

Comment: This is definitely not the episode of the "outer Limits", it's a standalone movie, I have been looking for the title forever now.

Comment: @Helen why does it not match the outer limits episode?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201897/robotic-spaceships-have-a-human-prisoner-to-maintain-them (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 34):

It's this episode of Outer Limits: [*The Human Operators*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Operators). I loved this episode, and the show for that matter. I can't recall seeing this same story in a scifi movie. The first three paragraphs of the plot from the linked Wikipedia article seem to describe most of what you remember:

> Humanity constructs advanced military spacecraft, but the ships learn to think for themselves. They kill their crews by disengaging the life support systems. However, they keep a small number of humans alive for repairs they cannot do themselves.
>
> One such ship, Starfighter 31, carries a father and his son, but once the father discovers that he is nothing more than a slave, he attempts to cripple the ship's computer core and is killed in the process of successfully destroying one of several spheres that apparently are critical to the core systems; in that way the ship cannot deactivate its automated defenses. This is witnessed by his son through the hatch doors.
>
> Once the son reaches adulthood and is able to fix the core systems (so that ship can deactivate its defenses), Starship 31 rendezvous with Starship 88, whose single young female crew member is brought aboard in order to mate with him and conceive a child. The male is shown what to do by the ship through "tutorials" and with guidance from the female. He falls in love with her, and due to her effect on him, he finds himself angering the ship on numerous occasions. At different points, they are both "racked"; they are subjected to energy bolt torture, despite the risk of her having a miscarriage. When she becomes pregnant with a girl, she is told to return to her own ship. He is threatened with death in the rack if he attempts to keep her aboard.

Answer (score 20):

This sounds an awful lot like the Outer Limits episode,  [The Human Operators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667972/) which IMDB describes as:

> On a ship controlled by an authoritarian computer maintained by human slaves, a man and woman learn that the ship fears them. The humans dream of sabotaging the ship's sentient control system and free themselves.

The synopsis on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Operators) mentions other matching details such as the ships being brought together in order to get the male and female to mate.